# How do I set a listview to have multiple columns, a checkbox, and make it send me a command one checking

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox, mvvm

I'm relatively new to wpf and mvvm, although I've been using code behind for a month without too much trouble.

I've got a listview, and I can have it display multiple columns, or I can have it display a checkbox and a label and have it include a command message.  But I'm not able to get it to do both.

From the xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="TemplateListView" ItemsSource="{Binding TemplateListItems}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTemplate}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Use}"  Command="{Binding TemplateListChangedCommand}" />
                <TextBox BindingGroup="{Binding Message}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

This ends up garbage.

If I use the code below, it will work perfectly but I don't get the message field this way:

```
<ListView x:Name="TemplateListView" ItemsSource="{Binding TemplateListItems}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTemplate}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Use}"  Command="{Binding TemplateListChangedCommand}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I tried using a grid inside the listview instead but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Grid` should have two `RowDefinitions` if you intend to display the `TextBox` beneath the `CheckBox`:

```
<ListView x:Name="TemplateListView" ItemsSource="{Binding TemplateListItems}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTemplate}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Use}" Command="{Binding TemplateListChangedCommand}" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Message}" Grid.Row="1" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Also note that you should bind the to `Text` property of the `TextBox`.

If you want columns, you should add two `ColumnDefinitions` to the `Grid`:

```
<ListView x:Name="TemplateListView" ItemsSource="{Binding TemplateListItems}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTemplate}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Use}" Command="{Binding TemplateListChangedCommand}" />
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Message}" Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```